# Angular Protractor with BrowserStack behind a proxy

Tags: angularjs, proxy, protractor, browserstack

I want to build a Testsuite for an Angular App. The testsuite should use the framework "Protractor".
When I start the testsuite local with `protractor local.config.js`, then the test are running successful.
When I start the testsuite with BrowserStack **without proxy**, also everything are okay.

Now my question:

What settings do I have to do if I want to perform the test by local browser stack behind a proxy?

Main BrowserStack configuration:

```
var
  proxy = 'http://proxy.example.com:8888';

exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    project: 'BrowserStack (beyond Proxy)',
    proxy: {
      proxyType: 'manual',
      httpProxy: proxy,
      sslProxy: proxy,
      },
    loggingPrefs: {
      driver: "FINE",
      server: "OFF",
      browser: "FINE"
    },

    'browserstack.user': 'USER_KEY',
    'browserstack.key': 'ACCESS_KEY', // show on BrowserStack

    // Needed for testing localhost
    'browserstack.local' : 'true',

    // Settings for the browser you want to test
    // (check docs for difference between `browser` and `browserName`
    'browserName' : 'chrome',
    'version' : '43.0',
    'os' : 'OS X',
    'os_version' : 'Yosemite',
    'resolution' : '1024x768'
  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
  specs: [
    'test/e2e/**/*.spec.js'
  ]
};
```

I call the script "BrowserStackLocal" with this parameters:

```
./BrowserStackLocal -v -proxyHost PROXY_DOMAIN -proxyPort PROXY_PORT $ACCESS_KEY localhost,$PORT,0
```

Stepts:

1. start the application on my local computer `node app.js`
2. start the script "BrowserStackLocal"
3. start the protractor with the browserstack configuration from above.

Comment: I have found that I can access from the browser stack "Live" on my application that runs locally.
Now it seems to be a problem with the Protractor not work via proxy.
How do I configure Protractor so that it can deal behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

When you are behind a proxy server, you need to do two things:

1. If you are testing your local server, you need to setup the Local Testing connection by passing the proxy details, which I assume you are doing.
2. You have to make sure the Selenium requests made via Protractor also reach BrowserStack. The easiest option would be to use [global-tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel) npm package. If your proxy is behind an Authentication, you can try using the [tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel) npm module.

Comment: Same problem here. Do you have an example of a protractor config that uses global-tunnel??

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need to use global-tunnel.  There is now a new configuration option webDriverProxy:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  webDriverProxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['*.spec.js'],
};
```